# Is there any way to update a devDependency version of a nested dependency?

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

In a react-native project, there is `mocha (9.2.0)` as a devDependency like the following -

**react-native-svg -**

```
"dependencies": {
  "css-select": "^5.1.0",
  "css-tree": "^1.1.3"
}
```

**css-tree -**

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "mocha": "9.2.0",
  ...
}
```

When I perform the app bundle, I found the `mocha` is there.

[image]

Now I want to upgrade the `mocha` version to `10.1.0`. I can do that by modifying the `package-lock.json`. But is it possible to do the same without modifying the `package-lock.json` by using the npm `override` or `resolution` or something similar to that?

Comment: Why don't use override?

Answer (score 1):

you can use patch-package https://github.com/ds300/patch-package, modify dependencies in `node_modules` and then patch it with `npx patch-package css-tree` or what package do you want to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command but it will still update your package.json ultimately

```
npm install mocha@10.1.0 --save --only=dev
```